# Get list of pages using an image hosted on Wikimedia commons through API

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

I'd like to get the file usage on other wikis for a given image on Wikimedia Commons through API.

For example the image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2015_Finland_opinion_polls.png is used in:

- Usage on da.wikipedia.org

  - Rigsdagsvalget i Finland 2015
- Usage on en.wikipedia.org

  - 2015 Finnish parliamentary election
  - Opinion polling for the 2015 Finnish parliamentary election
- Usage on fr.wikipedia.org

  - Élections législatives finlandaises de 2015
- Usage on it.wikipedia.org

  - Elezioni parlamentari in Finlandia del 2015
- Usage on no.wikipedia.org

  - Riksdagsvalget i Finland 2015

How can i get this information using API? I tried both the [wikimedia commons API](https://tools.wmflabs.org/magnus-toolserver/commonsapi.php) and the [Mediawiki Image API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images) but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [*Globalusage* API call](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bglobalusage).

For your example the URL would be:

https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=globalusage&titles=File:2015_Finland_opinion_polls.png

Comment: thanks you, that was exactly what i was looking for!